# Putting Struct information into one big array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

I am looking for a way to put an entire structs information into an array. The reason for this is that a function I am working with requires an array of information to read from. Instead of calling this function X amount of times, where X is the number of fields I have in the struct, I would like to put the whole blob of information into a single array and send that off to be written.

This is what I was thinking:

```
typedef struct
{
    short powerLevel[100];
    short unitInfo[4];
    short unitSN[6];
} MyDeviceData;

int main()
{ 
    MyDeviceData *devicePtr;
    MyDevieData deviceObject;

    short structInfo[sizeof(MyDeviceData) / sizeof(short)];

    //put all of MyDeviceData arrays into single array structInfo
    ????????

    //call function with new array that has all the structs information

   /* do stuff */
```

Is this at least in the right direction?

EDIT!!:  Ok I settled on the following solution in case other people come across this question in the future. Hope its not too bad:

```
//memcpy struct values into appropriately sized array. Used + 1 to advance 
//pointer so the address of the pointer was not copied in and just the relevant
//struct values were

memcpy(structInfo, &dataPointer + 1, sizeof(MyDeviceData);

//If not using pointer to struct, then memcpy is easy

memcpy(structInfo, &deviceObject, sizeof(deviceObject));
```

The caveats being what chrisaycock and Sebastian Redl already mentioned, that being bit packing appropriately and making sure the array initializing is using portable code to ensure correct size for it to hold the structs information.

Comment: does this help? http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/15042/

Comment: Are you trying to write out the raw bytes?

Answer (score 3):

Your size calculation for the structInfo array is not really portable - although it's very unlikely in practice, there could be padding between the members of MyDeviceData.

```
short structInfo[100 + 4 + 6];
memcpy(structInfo, devicePtr->powerLevel, 100*sizeof(short));
memcpy(structInfo + 100, devicePtr->unitInfo, 4*sizeof(short));
memcpy(structInfo + 100 + 4, devicePtr->unitSN, 6*sizeof(short));
```

This is portable. Anything beyond that is probably not. It would of course be good if you had some constants to replace those magic numbers.

Comment: As an added comment, I recomend overloading the function to take an argument of your struct type, and put this logic in there, rather than in main.  This will keep your main loop clean and concise, as well as clarify the purpose of this somewhat unusual logic.

Comment: Thanks for the portability tip, I will read more on it and change it. However, if I had a struct with say 20 arrays in it of various information, it looks like 20 memcpy calls would have to be done, which isn't appealing.

Comment: You might be able to do similar logic using a short*, and casting you device pointer to a short pointer... but this could lead to chaos under the padding scenario mentioned and is bad for other reasons!

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char structInfo[(100 + 4 + 6)*sizeof(short)];
unsigned char *tmpAddress = structInfo;
memcpy(tmpAddress , devicePtr->powerLevel, 100*sizeof(short)); 
tmpAddress +=100*sizeof(short);
memcpy(tmpAddress , devicePtr->unitInfo, 4*sizeof(short));
tmpAddress +=4*sizeof(short);
memcpy(tmpAddress , devicePtr->unitSN, 6*sizeof(short));
tmpAddress +=6*sizeof(short)
```

if you are trying to save that in a byte array instead